# How do I cast a number to a set

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I think this is a bit of a beginner MDX question. I'm trying to get the following as a calculated member:

```
Max(Min([Measures].[My Data] / 0.2, 1), 0)
```

I get `#VALUE!` as the result, I presume because Min/Max work on sets, and `[Measures].[My Data]` is in the same scope, so it is a scalar. Basically I want `My Data / .2`, as long as it is between 1 or zero. If greater than 1, I want 1, if less than 0 I want 0.

Is there any way to cast [Measures].[My Data] to a set? Such that set functions will work on it?

Answer (score 2):

This calculated measure can help or you have to use Min/Max functions?

```
with 
member [Measures].[Value] as ([Measures].[My Data] / 0.2)
member [Measures].[Test] as
IIF([Measures].[Value] < 1, 
    IIF([Measures].[Value] < 0, 0,[Measures].[Value])
, 1)
```

`[Measure].[Test]` is the output you need.

HTH